# Find the values of $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ where the system $Ax=x$ allows a solution different to the null one

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have to find the values of $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ where the system $Ax=x$ allows a solution different to the null one, and then solve the system with those values I found of the following matrix:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&2&\\2&a+1&a&\\-1&a&0&\end{bmatrix}$

So, considering the statement, what I did is the following:

First,

$Ax-x=0$

Then,

$(A-I)x=0$

And after, I found the cases of $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ where:

$Det(A-I)=0$

And, I did that, considering that the system will admit a solution different from the trivial one, if the determinant of the matrix of this particular system is equal to zero. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yep, that's precisely the method, and what you're computing is called the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial).

Comment: To be precise just  $\det(A-I)=0$ is not the characteristic polynomial. It will only determine if $\lambda=1$ is an eigen value of $A$ or not. The characteristic polynomial is $\det(A-\lambda I)$, which will be a polynomial in the variable $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning is correct. It remains perhaps to check the calculations:
By applying the indicated method, I find $a \in \{0,5\}$.
For $a=0$, I find $x\in \mathbb{R}(2,4,-1)$. And for $a=5$, $x\in \mathbb{R}(10,1,-5)$.